# Haar measure on SU(n)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, volume, haar-measure

I can't seem to find a formula for Haar integral

$$ \int_{SU(n)} F(U) d \mu$$

The integration will probably be executed using some parametrization with $n^2 -1$ parameters as I believe $SU(n)$ is related to $S^{d^2 -1}$.
What interests me is the most general formula, as I can't seem to find any specifics for $n > 2$. 
Something that may simplify the concept is the fact, that I want to integrate volumes of balls $$ B(g,\epsilon) = \{ U \in SU(n): |U-g| \leq \epsilon \}. $$

Is there any material on that or could anyone show me a way of building such a measure?

EDIT: $F$ should be such that the result is a volume of a ball in $SU(n)$ . From one source I see that for $SU(2)$ $ F(\theta, \phi, \psi) $ (where $\phi, \psi, \theta$ are Euler angles) is a *central function* satisfying $F(ghg^{-1}) = F(h)$. That simplifies $F (\theta, \phi, \psi) = F (\phi)$. The exact formula for $F$ is given as 1 if $| \sin \frac{\phi}{2}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 \sqrt{2}}$, 0 otherwise. $\phi$ is the spectral angle.

Comment: $SU(2)$ is homeomorphic to $S^3 = S^{2^2-1}$. For $n>2$ this is not true; they just have the same dimension. But more importantly, please add more information to your question. Does $F$ have any particular properties? If not, I don't think you can say anything.

Comment: @Rhys I think that I may have mislead you, because as in the edited version I want to integrate over the whole space not by a ball.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a description of the Haar measure on $SU(n)$ in

"Generalized Euler Angle Parametrization for SU(N)" Tilma, Sudarshan

and

"Composite parameterization and Haar measure for
all unitary and special unitary groups" Spengler, Huber, Hiesmayr.